# How to keep a js script in local project structure and use it [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, sisense

I need help. I'm working on an Angular project. I'm making some API calls (GET/PUT) to a remote server. To save time and prformance of my application I thought let's keep it in my local itself. So, I downloaded the JS file and kept it in *assets* folder.

Previously the code was:

```
private loadMySisenseJs(): Promise<any> {
    ...
    // load required js
    this.sisenseJsLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sisenseJsSrc = 'https://sisense-dev.dummy.com/js/sisense.js'; // FROM SERVER
        ...    
        });
        return this.sisenseJsLoadPromise;
    }
}
```

Now the code is:

```
private loadMySisenseJs(): Promise<any> {
    ...
    // load required js
    this.sisenseJsLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sisenseJsSrc = '../../../assets/sisense.js'; // FROM LOCAL
        ...    
        });
        return this.sisenseJsLoadPromise;
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting:
[image]

I tried these things also:

1.
**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

2. 

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
        ...
        "(local path to js file)/sisense.js"
    ]
```

But still the same problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your local file using some web server. Or a easier way would be to just import local file as module.

```
import "path/to/localfile.js";
```

then you can directly use methods/variables from that file.

Comment: Ok I'll quickly try this. Give me 2 mins.

Comment: But I also need to store it in a variable like this `const sisenseJsSrc = '(local path)/sisense.js';` Plz help.

Comment: Whats the usecase to store in variable. You can try dynamic imports using ```import("path")``` if path can be dynamic.